# How can you find the probability that an element is part of a sampled set?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, sampling

Let's say I have a set of scalar values $V$ that I sampled from a set $S$.  I want to test whether a given value $X$ could be a member of $S$ or not.

I understand that if the values in $V$ are distributed normally, then we can find the mean and standard deviation, after which you can determine the probability of occurrence for any particular value based on how many standard deviations your value differs from the mean.

However, what happens if the values are not distributed normally?  For example, what if you have 2 peaks in your data?

Example: If you sample the ratio of pelvis width to femur length over a large number of adults, you will have 2 peaks, one for men and one for women.  Now, my question is, given a particular ratio, how can we determine the probability that the subject was human? (i.e. probability that the ratio is part of our set $S$.)

Comment: First: I don't understand if you want to find the probability that X belongs to V or to S, and if X is a value within V or just any value to assess against S (and then what is V?). Second: (a) do you know the distribution of S, (b) do you infer the distribution of S by the sample V, or (c) you want to explicitly avoid assuming a distribution for S?

Comment: For the example the answer is "you cannot." For instance, if I am studying baboon morphology and have selected a specimen at random from a population of baboons, then regardless of the ratio, the answer is there is a zero probability it's human. If instead I select a subject at random from a human population, the answer is one: the subject is certainly human. In general, *depending on how I am selecting the specimen,* the answer could be anywhere between zero and one.  For more on these concepts, read the threads related to [tag:bayesian].

Comment: FairMiles, whuber: Let me express it a different way.  Let's say we take a picture of 1000 cars that pass by our road and measure the diameter of the wheels.  Now somebody tells us a diameter X, and we want to know whether or not X is likely to be the diameter of a car wheel.  In this case, we don't exactly know the distribution of the data, but we know that there are multiple peaks in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think your data consists of multiple peaks or components, each of which might be normally distributed, you could try a Gaussian mixture model, see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rkl30Fr2S38).

For your example with the femur lengths, you would have one Gaussian component corresponding to the male ratios and one Gaussian component corresponding to the female ratios and the distribution over all humans is an equal mixture of these two.

Comment: Oh, although whuber raises a valid point. This would not help you decide if a value is part of your set, it would only allow you to calculate the probability for the value given that it came from the same set.